# How to delete objects by touch in swift Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touches

I am trying to delete an image that is moving by touch and only that image. I spawn multiple images of that same image and I only want to delete the ones that are being touched. How can I do this? Any ideas? I am running IOS app Game and `SpriteKit`.

```
import SpriteKit





 `class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
        myLabel.fontSize = 45
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }





    func generateNode() {
        let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullets")
        Bullet.name = "generatedNode"

    }





     func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch?
        if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
        {
            for Bullet in self.nodesAtPoint(location)
            {
                if Bullet.name == "generatedNode"
                {
                    Bullet.removeFromParent()
                }
            }

        }
    }
    }


    func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
```

Comment: You might be needing a `UIGestureRecognizer`, though I am not sure. Can you show your code where you are facing issues?

Comment: I put my code i hope that helps. i don't know how to put the rest so i hope it helps.

Comment: I think you may be able to get away without using a gesture recogniser if you want, though it's more "Apple" if you do use one. I think your issue here is that you're putting the node in touchesCancelled. This is only called when a touch is programmatically cancelled by a gesture recogniser or something. Try putting the code in touchesBegan or touchesEnded

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. I'm very new to this or swift. If you have any tips for that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tips for me that... * that is what I meant

Comment: I did as you said but it seems to not be the solution. It says "Method 'touchesended(_withevent:)' with objective-c selector 'touchesended.withevent:' conflicts with method 'touchesended(_withevent:)'from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same objective c selector". It is also the same with touches began.

Comment: use `override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) `